# Question about the implementation of "Marshal.GetActiveObject(System.String)" method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, marshalling

I'm trying to connect to a running Solid Edge instance, but **I am getting the following error**:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject(System.String)'
```

I’ve been searching **about this error** and **I found that**:

- "[API was originally removed from .NET Core since COM support was not included.](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37617)", but it is on .NET framework.
- And "that API is a simple wrapper over the [Running Object Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/com/registering-objects-in-the-rot) (ROT)" so there is a solution pulling function directly from [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs#L2404) and [modifying the Marshal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010510/no-definition-found-for-getactiveobject-from-system-runtime-interopservices-mars).

**I want to make another solution**, more accurate for my project. The idea is to **make a DLL with .NET Framework 4.8.1** and then **use it** on another projects that are programmed **with .NET Core 7**. In this way I made this code snippet for the DLL:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 
namespace SolidEgde.OpenSDK
{
    public static class Comunication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Connects to or starts a new instance of Solid Edge.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startIfNotRunning"></param>
        /// <returns>
        /// An object of type SolidEdgeFramework.Application.
        /// </returns>
        public static SolidEdgeFramework.Application Connect(bool startIfNotRunning)
        {
            SolidEdgeFramework.Application application = null;
 
            try
            {
                // Attempt to connect to a running instance of Solid Edge.
                application = (SolidEdgeFramework.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject(PROGID.SolidEdge_Application);
            }
            catch { throw; }
 
            if (application != null)
                application.Visible = true;
 
            return application;
        }
    }
    public static class PROGID
    {
        public const string SolidEdge_Application = "SolidEdge.Application"; // HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SolidEdge.Application
    }
}
```

And then I call It from a test project, like this:

```cs
namespace Testeo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SolidEdgeFramework.Application application = null;
 
            application = SolidEgde.OpenSDK.Comunication.Connect(true);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error mentioned at the beginning.

PS: In my project I am trying to connect to an instance of the Solid Edge CAD program.

Comment: Create a different namespace for your code so you can specify your version of Runtime.InteropServices instead of the standard Core version

Comment: Thank for the answer @jdweng. 
If I understand you correctly, the projects already have different namespaces, and each one is using a different Target framework. .Net Framework 4.8 for the DLL (namespace = SolidEgde.OpenSDK) and .Net Core 7 for the executable (namespace = Testeo).

Comment: The you simply change the using statement : using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  System and Runtime are the namespace and InterpService is the Class.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ignorance @jdweng , but I don't understand what you're asking me to change.
Are you saying that I have to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` in the executable part?

Comment: You have the source code.  Change at top namespace System.Runtime.InteropServices to namespace MySystem.Runtime.InteropServices.  Then top of your module : using MySystem.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: I'm sorry @jdweng but that doesn't make sense for me

Comment: You are getting this exception because you tried to cheat with a 4.8.1 targeted assembly.  That approach cannot work, it still runs with the .NET7 version of the Marshal class and it doesn't have this method.  You can replace it, [the pinvoke](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,2404) is not complicated.

Comment: Libraries are similar to folders in a file system.  System.Runtime.InteropServices is in the roots Library System.  One of the sub libraries in System is Runtime.  The Library Runtime  have a sub library InteropServices which contains many classes.  In the c# modules you add the namespace attribute to the code to tell the compiler where to place the code. You created a new namespace SolidEgde.OpenSDK.  Large project it is possible the two child project contain the same class but different versions of the class a you have to specify the full names\class to distiquish between the tow classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @Hans Passant, I search more info about legacy dll .NET Framework components and .NET Core integration and the answer is:

**No, It is not possible to have both on a project in a safe way.**

Why?

- They target a different set of assemblies (mscorlib vs. System.Runtime) which causes incompatibilities since all usages of types are prefixed with the assembly the type is from.
- .NET Core can reference .NET Framework assemblies. This allows to reference the assembly and compile successfully. BUT this doesn't guarantee a successful execution on runtime, since .NET Core doesn't provide all the APIs from .NET Framework.

References to this problem:

- [Use .NET Core with legacy .NET framework dlls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260792/use-net-core-with-legacy-net-framework-dlls)
- [How to use .net framework dll in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/765102/how-to-use-net-framework-dll-in-net-core)
- [Using a .net core dll with .net framework app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51269479/using-a-net-core-dll-with-net-framework-app)